# I can't sum range? have run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

What's wrong with my code? run time error 1004

```
Sub SumAboveF()
    Dim r As Range, rAbove As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = ActiveCell
    Set rAbove = Range(r.Offset(-1).End(xlToLeft).Row)
    r.Formula = "=SUM(" & rAbove.Address & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Because `r.Offset(-1).End(xlToLeft).Row` resolves to a number like `2`. That is not a valid `Range` address.

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & ActiveCell.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Address & ")"`  ?   If that's not it then maybe explain exactly what you want to sum up.

Comment: @TimWilliams I want to sum values in all cells to the left of the ActiveCell

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks! I am very grateful to you!!!

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you help with all this task? https://stackoverflow.com/q/70903249/18050394

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```vb
Dim rng As Range

With ActiveCell
    Set rng = .EntireRow.Cells(1).Resize(1, .Column - 1)
    .Formula = "=SUM(" & rng.Address & ")"
End With
```