# Need sum some values left from activeCell. Where error?

Tags: excel, vba

Yeah i ve done it! But i need one thing -if activecell in column b - paste =Page1!E2

```
Sub FOT()
Dim rgb
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
With ActiveCell
    Set Rng = .EntireRow.Cells(2).Resize(1, .Column - 1)
   .Offset(0, 1).Select
   rgb = Evaluate("=SUM(" & Rng.Address & ")")
End With
If rgb < 1500001 Then
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Page1!E2"
Else
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Page1!F2"
End If
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: What should happen if the active cell is cell `A1`? What exactly are those *some values left from activeCell*? Please describe a practical example e.g. for cell `E5`.

Comment: Do you really want a sub or do you actually need a function?  You want to do this from in a cell specifically or do you want to push a button (or whatever) to run a macro?

Comment: @VBasic2008 B2 - always be the first cell in massive, A1 as First name and last name of worker. And yes, if active cell is B2, i don't need to go left for 1 cell

Comment: @VBasic2008 page1E2 =210000, page1F2 =198000 also Column B is January, Column C is February and etc.

Comment: @Skin push a button, but if you can show both variants it will be cool)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70903249/edit) instead of adding information in comments

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad done

Comment: When you create such a sub, you usually want to apply it to a whole column. Please do clarify. What is the name of the worksheet where you are doing this and in which column (is it column `N`?) do you want the results (sums)? Have you considered using a simple Excel SUM formula, e.g. `=SUM($B2:$M2)`, and putting it in an IF statement: `=IF(SUM($B2:$M2)<1500001,Page1!$E$2,Page2!$F$2)`?

Comment: @VBasic2008 i tried to resolve this problem by this formula,but the problem in circle cells. Can you give your email, i ll send you my file, because it difficulte to explain here/

Comment: My email is somewhere in [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814069/vbasic2008). Let me know if you have sent it.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Sent to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub FOT()
Dim rgb
If ActiveCell.Column() = 2 Then
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Page1!E2"
Exit Sub
End If

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
With ActiveCell
    Set Rng = .EntireRow.Cells(2).Resize(1, .Column - 1)
   .Offset(0, 1).Select
   rgb = Evaluate("=SUM(" & Rng.Address & ")")
End With
If rgb < 1500001 Then
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Page1!E2"
Else
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Page1!F2"
End If
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```